# Traversing and filtering a tree in Java

Tags: java

I have a non-binary tree in Java (see code below), and given an input string I need to filter its nodes by node name. If I find a node, then the entire parent chain should be present in the result, even though the parent names don't match.

I thought about traversing the tree upwards, starting from the leaves, but not sure how to do that. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

The result should be the same tree but with filtered leaves, not a list of leaves.

Java code:

```
public class Tree<T> {

    Node<T> root = null;


    public Tree(Node <T> rootNode) {
        root = rootNode;
    }


    public Node<T> searchFromRoot(int idToSearch) {
        return recursiveSearch(idToSearch, root);
    }



    private Node<T> recursiveSearch(int idToSearch, Node<T> node){


        List <Node<T>>children = node.getChildren(); 

        Node<T> result = null;

        for ( Node<T> node2 : children ) {

            result = recursiveSearch(idToSearch, node2);

            if (result != null)
                break;

        }

        return result;
     }


    public Node<T> getRoot() {
        return root;
   }



}


public class Node<T> {


    private List<Node<T>> children = new ArrayList<Node<T>>();

    private Node<T> parent = null;

    private T data = null;

    private int id = 0;


    public static final int NODE_TYPE_FOLDER = 0;

    private int nodeType = 0;

    public Node(int id, int nodeType, T data) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nodeType = nodeType;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Node(T data, Node<T> parent) {
        this.data = data;
        this.parent = parent;
    }


    public boolean isLeaf() {
        if (this.children.size() == 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }



// getters and setters

    public void addChild(int id, int nodeType, T data) {
        Node<T> child = new Node<T>(id,nodeType,data);
        child.setParent(this);
        this.children.add(child);
    }

    public void addChild(Node<T> child) {
        child.setParent(this);
        this.children.add(child);
    }


    public boolean isRoot() {
        return (this.parent == null);
    }


}
```

Comment: This sounds like your homework ;-)

Comment: It may, but it's an issue that I'm trying to solve at work, I have a screen with folders, a search button, and I need to filter the tree.

Comment: You should not start at the leaves. What's the point of your tree structure then? You can traverse the tree from the root, and output the path if need be. You might want to check a post-order traversal for instance.

Comment: Is there any reason to use the code above - because you wrote, it represents folders. Java provides you for instance with https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html to make this working using a given API. If this is also possible I can share an example.

Comment: the folders are not folder files, they are folders I store in the database

Comment: Do we need to create a new tree? or we just add an extra `boolean` in each node, indicating that this node is belong to the filtered list?

Comment: either way will work, my preference is to have a `boolean`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a `list` which contains all leaves, and you need to search for `name`:

```
HashSet<String> result = new HashSet();
for( Node leaf: list)
   search(false, name, leaf, result);


public void search(boolean found, String name, Node node, HashSet<String> result){
    if(node == null)
       return;
    found = found ? found : node.getName().equals(name);
    if(found)
       result.add(node.getId());

    search(found, name, node.getParent(), result);
}
```

Update:

So, rather than an `ArrayList`, we can just store a `HashSet` which contains all filtered node's id, so you can traverse the tree from the root, and check if the node's id is in the result set or not, which help you to rebuild the tree.

Comment: The result needs to be a tree, showing only the filtered leaves

Comment: @pgschr there is only one way from root to any node in a `tree`, so an arraylist is enough, except when there are more than one match? so are there more than one match?

Comment: right, but the final result needs to be a tree with filtered leaves. Each leave has one way to root node, so the final result should be all the paths to the root node from the leaves that meet the search criteria

Comment: @pgschr this is extra requirement, and you need to put them to your question. Be specific of what you are asking :)

Comment: you're right, the question wasn't 100% clear, I added an update

Answer (score 0):

You need a Post order traversal algorithm. It should be almost identical to your method `recursiveSearch()`. You can google the algorithm. It's pretty easy to implement.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Post-order